# How To Get Files app

Tags: applications

I do not have a "MyFiles" or "Files" app on my Samsung Galaxy Note 2 smartphone. How do I find this app? I have tried sobbing into my handkerchief. I have tried looking in the index.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please note that asking to find an app is off-topic on this site. As [Djd080 pointed out](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/150396/16575), you can use any 3rd party [File Manager](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman) if your device doesn't ship with one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to get into whatever is saved on your phone and do not have a "file explorer" app. There are plenty of 3rd party apps such as astro (doesn't have to be this one) that will do the job for you.